# Speech_Recognizer won't recognize my voice

Tags: python, speech-recognition

i'm testing out this module named Speech_Recognizer but for some reason it won't recognize my voice.here's the code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("speak:")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said: {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("sorry couldn't hear that")
```

The main problem/the reason why I think it won't recognize my voice even when I'm shouting is that it's stuck at the print("speak") and won't do anything after that, I've even tried using a new earphone w mic but it still didn't work can anyone pls help me.

Comment: You forgot to calibrate threshold of ambient noise. Add `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)` before the  `print("speak:")` line.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to calibrate threshold of ambient noise. Add `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)` before the `print("speak:")` line.